# Copy URL to clipboard and show and hide message

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, clipboard

Would like to copy current URL to clipboard show a notice message and hide again after few seconds. I've seen this function online.

---

[image]

---

The animated gif shows how it should work. Javascript part is extracted from a website with a working example and the same HTML and CSS code used, but the javascript is not formatted correctly yet, because i extracted only the part this function needs. Can someone help me write the javascript correctly? Fiddle is ready to go:

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fmeb486q/)

---

Extracted javascript

```
  events: {
            "click .share": "onShareClick"
        },
        onMouseEnter: function() {},
        onShareClick: function(e) {
            var t = this;
            this.$el.find(".share").addClass("show-notice"), setTimeout(function() {
                t.$el.find(".share").removeClass("show-notice")
            }, 3e3);
            var n = document.createElement("textarea");
            n.value = location.href, document.body.appendChild(n), n.select(), document.execCommand("copy"), document.body.removeChild(n)
        },
```

HTML

```
<div class="share">
     <img src="images/share.svg">
     <span class="share-notice">Link copied to clipboard</span>
     <span class="mouseenter-notice">Share</span>
</div>
```

Comment: No not at all have seen those... thanks for the input, but made exactly the example (gif animation) what it should do, made the css for it and html which i think will work fine, but would like help with the javascript.

Comment: Here's a working plunkr: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/dZh5ebJOFkDITqaq?preview Test that on Safari, please

Comment: Chris THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think all is working exactly like i would like, with same HTML and CSS combined

Comment: Can i flag you as the perfect answer? Only can give you a 1

Comment: The example is working perfectly, but implementing not yet, does it work when working locally (mamp)?

Comment: It should absolutely work on a local server, yes. Make sure the CSS and JS is actually loaded. If you can, don't develop on Safari. Use Chrome or Firefox until stuff works, then test for compatibility.

Comment: Testing on Chrome right now, example works perfectly and exactly, but implementing it doesn't work, i changed the jquery version into the version you used.. not working right now... what could it be..missing something i feel

Comment: Where did you put the CSS and JS files? What are they called? Are you sure your HTML is properly referencing them? This sounds like you're having trouble stating the proper `src` for the script and the correct `href` for the stylesheet link.

Comment: Don't understand why it is working perfectly in Plunker and not on Safari or Chrome...when implemented. I call the jquery, put the script you written into main.js calling that, CSS and HTML are ready to go. Maybe i'am echo the share.php into the multiple pages so i don't need to change all just that one file, could that give a problem..

Comment: The problem was this: Needed to add $(document).ready(function() {
 and end tag }); to your existing written script to make it work. Why it works in fiddle and Plunker without that i don't understand :) Thank you Chris very nice written script!

Comment: Right, or you can move your own script to the end of `<body>` so it runs after all HTML exists. Apparently plunkr is auto-fixing this so I didn't realize it wouldn't work elsewhere.

Comment: Yes didn't realized that at first plunkr worked that way, thought you could copy one-to-one :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the div is the first of member of the 'share' class within the doc you could try:

```js
const div = document.getElementsByClassName('share')[0];
const shareNotice = document.getElementById('share-notice');
const mouseoverNotice = document.getElementById('mouseover-notice');

div.onclick = () => {
    window
  .navigator
  .clipboard
  .writeText(window.location.href);
  
  shareNotice.style.display = 'initial';
  
  window.setTimeout(() => shareNotice.style.display = 'none', 1500);  
};

div.onmouseover = () => mouseoverNotice.style.display = 'initial';

div.onmouseleave = () => mouseoverNotice.style.display = 'none';
```

```css
.share { cursor: pointer }

#share-notice { display: none; }

#mouseover-notice { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="share">
     x
     <span id="share-notice">Link copied to clipboard</span>
     <span id="mouseover-notice">Share</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i am not a javascript wizzkid, need some more info to implement this. Working example maybe?

Comment: There you go. Do you need help displaying and hiding the message, too?

Comment: I added the message-displaying/hiding logic, just in case

Comment: Again thank you, but i don't understand the implementation of the code you gave me... does not copy the URL and show and hide the notice message on copy to clipboard and no use of the existing css and html in the example. Oh sorry you have changed it... will take a look

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't seem to help you. I'll try to explain...The css initially hides the two messages. The JS part selects the div to be clicked and the two messages; it then attaches listeners for click-, mouseover- and mouseleave-events on the div; on click the url is copied to the clipboard, and the share-message displayed and hidden again after 1.5 secs; on mouseover the other msg is shown and hidden again on mouseleave.

Comment: Getting lots of errors in my js file when implementing this. Not working sorry... really appreciate your help!

Comment: What kind of errors? Notice that I changed the classes on the two messages into ids for conveniences sake.

Comment: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: I havent seen an error like that before. May I ask the context in which you are trying to make this work?

Comment: It's a error produced in this example, but i can get it to work. Pasting the code into my main.js makes other scripts not work correctly anymore. Maybe has to do with ending tags? Do you have to use id tags? Don't use them a lot.

Comment: Without a more detailed error message I can only guess why your other scripts break. You don't have to use ids, it's just the way I chose to get a reference to the affected html elements. Use whatever makes sense to you in the context of your project. If you can get it to work, then I guess I've answered your question.

Comment: Having looked at the pic you provided via the suggested edit, I think you might get it to work when moving the code I've given you into the call to $(document).ready().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198094/discussion-between-andre-nuechter-and-kp83).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the clipboard API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

For convenience you might want to use clipboard js: https://clipboardjs.com/

You can access the current url with `window.location.href`.

Comment: Thanks have seen the clipboardjs, but bit stuck implementing what i have now to javascript to make it all work.